# jquery inside javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Sorry for asking many questions,
My doubt is:

```
 <form id ="myform" onSubit="return validatefields()" >
```

all fields(for some of them I have same class, so need to validates all the elements having the same class)

```
function validatefields(){
   $(".someclass").each(function(index) {
   //some validation
    });
}
```

I am not sure if this is the valid syntax. Can anyone help me with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return a value so that the form will know whether to continue or not.

```
 function validatefields(){
       var valid = false; //set to true if all inputs validated
       $(".someclass").each(function(index) {
           //some validation
           //if valid:
           valid = true;
        });
        return valid; //if this returns false, the script will stop, else it will submit
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<form id ="myform" onSubit="return validatefields()" >
```

To

```
 <form id ="myform" onsubmit="return validatefields()" >
```

1. Case (onsubmit) is not really important, but spelling is...
   (#2 deleted after remark from @shad)

Comment: @Shad, indeed you are correct. I was sure I had done it without the 'return'.

Comment: That was a typing type but in actual code its onsubmit.Thanks for answering me.